# Error in Paypal Adaptive Payments Refund (code : 589061)

Tags: codeigniter, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using PayPal Adaptive Payments Pro PayFlow CodeIgniter Library ([Click Here](http://www.binpress.com/app/paypal-adaptive-payments-pro-payflow-codeigniter-library/140)). When i try to refund the amount, I got this error message :

I have referred paypal error code, it says "Receiver mail is invalid for this Refund".
But I don't know how to solve this problem.

Can anyone help this ?

```
   Array
(
    [Errors] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Receiver] => 
                    [Category] => Application
                    [Domain] => PLATFORM
                    [ErrorID] => 589061
                    [ExceptionID] => 
                    [Message] => The receiver receiver@mail.com is invalid for this refund
                    [Parameter] => receiver@mail.com
                    [Severity] => Error
                    [Subdomain] => Application
                )

    )

[Ack] => Failure
[Build] => 10902368
[CorrelationID] => dd093046f0e1e
[Timestamp] => 2014-05-15T22:04:29.865-07:00
[EncryptedTransactionID] => 
[RefundFeeAmount] => 
[RefundGrossAmount] => 
[RefundHasBecomeFull] => 
[RefundNetAmount] => 
[RefundStatus] => 
[RefundTransactionStatus] => 
[TotalOfAllRefunds] => 
[Receiver] => Array
    (
        [Amount] => 
        [Email] => 
        [InvoiceID] => 
        [PaymentType] => 
        [Primary] => 
    )

[RawRequest] => ReturnAllen_USUSDAP-7EU21334NX145763S1.32receiver@mail.com87D13041FU8962320
[RawResponse] => 2014-05-15T22:04:29.865-07:00Failuredd093046f0e1e10902368589061PLATFORMApplicationErrorApplicationThe receiver receiver@mail.com is invalid for this refundreceiver@mail.com
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The email you are using to complete the refunds does not exist, which is why you are getting that error.

You need a valid email. Also you need to use all emails affiliated if you are refunding an adaptive payment.

I found this reference to your exact error at WHMCS:

[WHMCS Documentation on invalid receiver email](http://docs.whmcs.com/PayPal#Invalid_Receiver_Email)